# using ulimit for current shell

Tags: macos, unix

I want to increase the hard limit of maxfiles using `ulimit -Hn` for the current bash shell. The problem is I can not do it without using `sudo`. But, when I do `sudo ulimit -Hn unlimited`, it does not effect the current shell's limits, instead it changes the limit for a child shell which is invoked for `sudo`.

Is there a way to achieve it for the current shell from with we are issuing the `ulimit` command? I am using Mac OS x 10.6.x.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And you can't change this before starting the shell without privileges?

Comment: what do you mean?Sorry, I did not get your question.

Comment: I mean, you could `sudo` to root, change the ulimit, `su` to normal user, execute script.

Comment: Something like this `sudo sh -c "ulimit -c 10 ; sudo -u $USER sh -c 'whoami ; ulimit -a'"`

Comment: No, I dont have the root's password.

Comment: And you normal user does not have sudo privileges? to change to hard resource limits you will need to have root privileges somehow, not sure if Mac OS X has some kind of more fine grained security system to let normals users set specific limits. But generally it would be a really bad idea if normal users could change that kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
sudo bash -c "ulimit -Hn unlimited; su $USER"
```

This will change the ulimit for the spawned shell and then change the user to yours. This will not raise the ulimits on your current shell, but rather create another with higher privileges and attach it to your terminal.

Still, you might not be able to increase the hard limit of opened files, even as root.. Process headers are only so big.